# Insert into two SQL Server tables and pass unique ID from one to the other

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm hoping someone can help me because, despite finding numerous other questions like this one, I can't seem to find an answer specific to this problem?

I have two tables, `TblReportsStore` and `TblReportsStoreComments` as follows:

[image: TblReportsStore]

[image: TblReportsStoreComments]

I want to add a new record to `TblReportsStore`, and then pass the `TblReportsStoreID` of that record to the `intReportID` column of a new record in `TblReportsStoreComments`. If it helps at all, the data is coming from a spreadsheet where the only changing data is the `txtSchoolID` and the `txtComment`.

Comment: How are you adding the data? Is `TblReportsStoreID` and Identity field?

Comment: You can use @@identity to get the last TblReportsStoreID added...and after that you execute a second command to add a new line in the table TblReportsStoreComments

Comment: @jonathon-quinn : can u share your code

Comment: @aguetat IF it is an identity field `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is far safer to use than `@@IDENTITY`  `@@IDENTITY` will return the last identity value generated in the current session not always the identity of the record you are adding.

Comment: @fred : i agree thank u for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `output`. This assumes that it is an Identity column. Otherwise you could use `NEWID()` with the values:

```
INSERT INTO TblReportsStore(...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.TblReportsStoreID,txtComment
INTO TblReportsStoreComments(intReportID,txtComment)
VALUES ...
```